# How to perform a JOIN Query in my criteria in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures, rdbms, outer-join

I am trying avoid Duplicate. Some times it shows duplicate records, I don't understand What I did wrong.

Here is my query

```
select 
        itemid = case when JEDnineDays.ItemID is null and JEDthirtyDays.ItemID is null and MECnineDays.ItemID is null then MECthirtyDays.ItemID
              when JEDnineDays.ItemID is null and JEDthirtyDays.ItemID is null then MECnineDays.ItemID
              when JEDnineDays.ItemID is null then JEDthirtyDays.ItemID
              else JEDnineDays.ItemID END
            ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),JEDnineDays.NineDaysSold) JEDNineDaysSold
        ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),MECnineDays.NineDaysSold) MECNineDaysSold
            ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),JEDthirtyDays.ThirtyDaysSold) JEDThirtyDaysSold
        ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),MECthirtyDays.ThirtyDaysSold) MECThirtyDaysSold
    into #days
    from 
    (select 
        itemid,
        sum(qtysold) as NineDaysSold
        from 
        [JC_ItemDSP10days]
    Where StoreID IN ('1201','1302','1400','1500')
        group by 
        ItemID
        ) as JEDnineDays

    full outer join
    (select 
        itemid,
        sum(qtysold) as NineDaysSold
        from 
        [JC_ItemDSP10days]
    Where StoreID IN ('2001','2400','2200')
        group by 
        ItemID
        ) as MECnineDays
    on(JEDnineDays.itemid = MECnineDays.itemid)
    full outer join 
    (select 
        itemid,sum(qtysold) as ThirtyDaysSold
        from 
        [JC_ItemDSP30Days]
    Where StoreID IN ('1201','1302','1400','1500')
        group by 
        ItemID
        ) as JEDthirtyDays
        on(JEDnineDays.itemid = JEDthirtyDays.itemid)
    full outer join 
    (select 
        itemid,sum(qtysold) as ThirtyDaysSold
        from 
        [JC_ItemDSP30Days]
    Where StoreID IN ('2001','2400','2200')
        group by 
        ItemID
        ) as MECthirtyDays
        on(JEDnineDays.itemid = MECthirtyDays.itemid)
```

Here is my result with Duplicate

```
ItemID    JEDNineDaysSold    MECNineDaysSold    JEDThirtyDaysSold    JEDThirtyDaysSold
391         NULL               NULL               0.75                   NULL
391         NULL               NULL               NULL                   2.50
```

> Most of the records are correct. But some of them are duplicate. What is wrong with my join

Comment: Is this sql server?

Comment: @joephillips no doubt. Of course. It's SQL Server

Comment: Does JEDnineDays have all of the ItemIds you want to return? If not, your joins won't work properly

Comment: @JoePhillips no JEDnineDays not having all the itemid, `table item` having all the `ItemID`. Then How should I join with `Item` Table

Comment: What does "correct" mean? All you have given is a query that is wrong. We can't read your mind. Please explain when a tuple belongs in the output based on what tuples are in the input. Why are you using full outer join? Do you realize that it returns the union of left outer join and right outer join? Do you realize outer joins return inner join rows plus unmatched rows extended by nulls? What is your DDL (since PK/UNIQUE & FKs affect join expectations)? Please read and act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy The example he provided is quite clear. It shows two rows with the same itemId. Anyone who knows how to answer his question will know how to interpret that example. Shame on the close brigade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I formatted the SQL so it was more readable. Also, the case statement at the top should just be a coalesce() or isnull() instead of a case statement.

The issue, I think, is that JEDnineDays doesn't actually contain all the ItemIds that are getting returned back so your other joins aren't joining with each other. You need to add multiple more conditions to your join statements.. something like:

```
on (JEDnineDays.itemid = MECnineDays.itemid OR JEDthirtyDays.itemid = MECnineDays.itemid OR ... etc)
```

Alternatively, and probably better, would be to do the `FROM Item` table and then join the rest of the tables. This will ensure that all tables can be joined back to an existing item. Once you KNOW that you will have all ItemIds in the FROM clause, you can change all your full outer joins to left joins if you want.

Fixed SQL:

```
select 
    itemid
    ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),JEDnineDays.NineDaysSold) JEDNineDaysSold
    ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),MECnineDays.NineDaysSold) MECNineDaysSold
    ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),JEDthirtyDays.ThirtyDaysSold) JEDThirtyDaysSold
    ,convert(DECIMAL(10,2),MECthirtyDays.ThirtyDaysSold) MECThirtyDaysSold
into #days
from Items i
full outer join (
    select itemid, sum(qtysold) as NineDaysSold
    from [JC_ItemDSP10days]
    where StoreID IN ('1201','1302','1400','1500')
    group by ItemID
) as JEDnineDays on(JEDnineDays.itemid = i.itemid)
full outer join (
    select itemid, sum(qtysold) as NineDaysSold
    from [JC_ItemDSP10days]
    where StoreID IN ('2001','2400','2200')
    group by ItemID
) as MECnineDays on(i.itemid = MECnineDays.itemid)
full outer join (
    select itemid, sum(qtysold) as ThirtyDaysSold
    from [JC_ItemDSP30Days]
    where StoreID IN ('1201','1302','1400','1500')
    group by ItemID
) as JEDthirtyDays on(i.itemid = JEDthirtyDays.itemid)
full outer join (
    select 
    itemid, sum(qtysold) as ThirtyDaysSold
    from [JC_ItemDSP30Days]
    where StoreID IN ('2001','2400','2200')
    group by ItemID
) as MECthirtyDays on(i.itemid = MECthirtyDays.itemid)
```

Comment: I did with item table. But it returns a lots of records. I am expecting nearly 20k records, but it returns all the items records, it nearly 130,000 records

Comment: It's providing the value without duplicate. But it returns all the null of four columns as well. which means it returns the item id which is not present in any of four table(`JEDnineDays,MECnineDays,JEDthirtyDays,MECthirtyDays`)

Comment: @mohamed If you switch to using left joins I think it will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your first subquery might not return all `ItemID` values.  A `full join` will put values from the other subqueries in different rows.

Start your query with a complete list, and join the rest to that:

```
from    (
        select  distinct ItemID
        from    JC_ItemDSP10days
        ) all_items
full outer join
        (
        ) sub1
on      sub1.ItemID = all_items.ItemID
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree they look like duplicates, but the initial ItemId CASE statement suggests similar/same values are coming from two different tables/views:

Specifically either:

- MECnineDays.ItemID
- JEDthirtyDays.ItemID

Also, not saying it's wrong, but the Full Outer Join usage looks fishy.

Suspect you might want to look at either, or both of the following:

- Union or Union All
- Group By, with Min()/Max()/Sum()

Once you've selected into #Days, would this produce the expected results?

```
select itemid,
Sum(IsNull(JEDNineDaysSold,0)) JEDNineDaysSold,
Sum(IsNull(MECNineDaysSold,0)) MECNineDaysSold,
Sum(IsNull(JEDThirtyDaysSold,0)) JEDThirtyDaysSold,
Sum(IsNull(MECThirtyDaysSold,0)) MECThirtyDaysSold
from #days
group by itemid
order by itemid
```

Comment: I agree that full outer join is fishy but I don't think unions or group bys are the solution